# highMaps map disappears when options are updated in react

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I'm using npm `react-highcharts-official package.

I have the following component

```
<div>
{ R.isNil(this.state.hcOptions) ? (
    <p>Loading...</p>
) : (
    <HighchartsReact
        highcharts={ Highcharts }
        constructorType={ 'mapChart' }
        options={ this.state.hcOptions }
        ref={ this.state.chartRef }
    />
)}
<div>
```

When I initially set this.state.hcOptions the map will render fine.

[image]

If I replace hcOptions with new data, or even just set it to the same data again the map disappears but the bottom grid still displays.

[image]

What do I need to do to change out options data and have the new map render?

Code Sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/7oz0m56px

The button at the bottom `Change Map Options` toggles the options. Loading either option set initially will load the map. toggling between the two causes the map it's self not to render.

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue in an online code editor like codesandbox? You can use it as a template: https://codesandbox.io/s/4r57245nw7

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/7oz0m56px

there is a button at the bottom `Change Map Options` to toggle between options

Comment: I've submitted an issue to the react-highchart-official project (https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react/issues/116)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That problem is a Highmaps regression bug, which fails since 7.1.0 and is reported here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/10617

Simplified example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tuokmpvy/

**The workaround** is to use an older Highmaps version:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/7.0.3/highmaps.js"></script>
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/poz8c51L/

Comment: Thank you, will try using the older version and let you know if that works

Comment: do you know when they would expect to release 7.1.2? (I assume that would contain the resolution from issue 10617?)

Comment: Hi @Seth McClaine, The release of 7.1.2 is planned for the next few days. And yes, the next version will contain the fix.